# How to get a color of a control in windows phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, colors, windows-phone

I have a button in my windows phone app. I setted its foreground color as "Red". I want to get this color to check if it is red I need to change it to blue.

How can I get the foreground color of a control (here it is  button) ?

Thanks,
Stallin

Comment: Unrelated to the technical part of question, in the example given you should not rely on control properties for application state. Controls should reflect the application state instead. e.g. change your status property from Alert to Pending (or whatever the business logic is) rather than *"if it is red make it blue"*.

Answer (score 3):

The foreground is basically a `Brush` object. You can get the object by,

`var colorbrush = mybutton.Foreground as Brush;`

`colorbrush` should contain the object. See [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brush%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to extract or change the color of this object.